# Getting the second occurrence from charindex function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the second occurrence of the space for below text. It should be the space after the 56, but I'm getting 15th position before the 56 as the first one.

```
select charindex(' ', 'Posted/edited: 56 days ago', 2)
```

Comment: The two is just an offset into the string -- so it starts looking for a space starting from position 2 instead of position 1 (the `o` rather than the `P`).

Comment: You need to nest 2 `CHARINDEX` functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set `START_LOCATION` for `CHARINDEX`. It means after what character `charindex` should be found. In our example, we need to find after `56`. So the code should looks like this:

```
select CHARINDEX(' ', 'Posted/edited: 56 days ago', 
    CHARINDEX('56', 'Posted/edited: 56 days ago', 0));
```

OUTPUT:

```
18
```

Answer (score 5):

You are already getting position of the second space (' ') in your query => 15. To clarify for example, you can use it to extract content from that point onwards, using following

```
select substring('Posted/edited: 56 days ago', 
           charindex(' ', 'Posted/edited: 56 days ago', 2) + 1, 
           len('Posted/edited: 56 days ago'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a start location is an excellent idea. However I would use the searchable character first occurrence +1 as a start location as situation may vary. So the solution would be:

Select charindex(' ','Posted/edited: 56 days ago',(charindex(' ', 'Posted/edited: 56 days ago') +1))

The output is ofc 18