# How to return characters after two dashes when present

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to return the first few characters before the first two dashes. I tried to use `LEFT(COL,CHARINDEX('-',COL))` but its not giving me the expected results.
example

```
12345-12-12
12345-1-12
12345-12
12345-12-1234
12345-A12
```

Expected results:

```
12345-12
12345-1
12345-12
12345-12
12345-A12
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the second occurrence from charindex function in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611930/getting-the-second-occurrence-from-charindex-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to solve these kinds of string problems... you just need to be creative with the functions SQL Server makes available to find the correct pattern and then usually use `substring`. Here is one possibility.

The logic is:

1. Find whether the string actually has 2 dashes, because if not it can be left untouched.
2. When there are two dashes, find the distance from the end of the second dash, by reversing the string, and then remove that amount using `substring`.

```
select
  case when y.Index1 > 0 then substring(x.[Value],1,len(x.[Value])-y.Index2) else x.[Value] end NewValue
from (
  values
  ('12345-12-12'),
  ('12345-1-12'),
  ('12345-12'),
  ('12345-12-1234'),
  ('12345-A12')
) x ([Value])
cross apply (
  values (patindex('%[-]%[-]%', x.[Value]), patindex('%[-]%', reverse(x.[Value])))
) y (Index1,Index2);
```

Returns:

| NewValue |
| --- |
| 12345-12 |
| 12345-1 |
| 12345-12 |
| 12345-12 |
| 12345-A12 |

Comment: What if there are 3 hyphens?

Comment: @dougp OP didn't ask for 3 hyphens :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution based on
[Getting the second occurrence from charindex function in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611930/getting-the-second-occurrence-from-charindex-function-in-sql-server)

```
create table #a (
    a varchar(50)
)
insert #a
values 
  ('12345-12-12')
, ('12345-1-12')
, ('12345-12')
, ('12345-12-1234')
, ('12345-A12')
, ('12345')
, ('12345-12-123-12345')

select a as 'input'
, CHARINDEX('-', a, 1) as 'index1'
, CHARINDEX('-', a, CHARINDEX('-', a, 1) + 1) as 'index2'
, left(a, case when CHARINDEX('-', a, CHARINDEX('-', a, 1) + 1) = 0 then len(a) else CHARINDEX('-', a, CHARINDEX('-', a, 1) + 1) - 1 end) as 'output'
from #a

drop table #a
```

| input | index1 | index2 | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345-12-12 | 6 | 9 | 12345-12 |
| 12345-1-12 | 6 | 8 | 12345-1 |
| 12345-12 | 6 | 0 | 12345-12 |
| 12345-12-1234 | 6 | 9 | 12345-12 |
| 12345-A12 | 6 | 0 | 12345-A12 |
| 12345 | 0 | 0 | 12345 |
| 12345-12-123-12345 | 6 | 9 | 12345-12 |